# simple_form selected: by name

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I have a simple_form collection which contains a list of languages. I want to select 'German' by default, but the selected: option in simple_form requires an id. I could obtain the id of 'German' but would hope that wasn't necessary.

```
= f.association :language, selected: // not sure what to put here
```

This works, but stinks (I will NOT be using such atrocious code):

```
= f.association :language, selected: Language.where("name = 'German'").first.id
```

I would hope for something like:

```
= f.association :language, selected: { |lan| lan.name == 'German' }
```

Every example I've found during the last hour involves the id. Not one example of how to select via the name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah, `SimpleForm` can accept proc for `selected` option. In your case the code is:

```
= f.association :language, selected: lambda { |lan| lan.name == 'German' }
```